# Filter the configurable products based on the child product's color in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, filter, color-swatches

In Magento 2 How to filter the configurable products based on the child product's color. For example, if the parent has 4 children with Green, Red, Yellow and Black colors. If I select green in the filter. image of Relevant child product(green) should be visible in place of the parent product image.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @JulianoVargas No